# MyBatis Oracle query not returning a result, but it should

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jakarta-ee, mybatis

I am migrating a MyBatis project from SQL Server to Oracle. A query that works fine with using SQL Server doesn't work when using MyBatis Oracle.
The query has 2 parameters. If I hard code the second parameter in the mapper, I get the result. If I copy the generated query and plug in the parameters in the log and run it, I get a result. Very strange.

```
    <sql id="employeeBranch">
        SELECT
            brn.branch AS id,
            brn.employee_id AS employeeId,
            brn.club_cd AS clubCode,
            brn.branch AS branchCode,
            brn.role_id AS roleId,
            'N' AS defaultBranch,
            branch.name AS description
        FROM EmployeeBranch brn, branch
        WHERE brn.employee_id = #{employeeId}
            AND brn.club_cd = branch.club_cd
            AND brn.branch = branch.branch
    </sql>

    <select id="getEmployeeBranch" resultType="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.EmployeeBranchBean">
        <include refid="employeeBranch"/>
            AND brn.branch = #{branch}
    </select>
```

If I hard code the passed parameter into #{branch}, the query works. If I take the logged query, plug in the params logged by MyBatis and run it manually it works. Using MyBatis 3.2.1

Here is the log: (notice no result. Pasting the query in SQL Dev with same params works. If I hard code the the '001' param, also works.)

```
09:40:10,768 DEBUG getEmployeeBranch:132 - ooo Using Connection [1836735260, URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@developmentdb1:1521:*****, UserName=********* , Oracle JDBC driver]
09:40:10,768 DEBUG getEmployeeBranch:132 - ==>  Preparing: SELECT empBr.branch AS id, empBr.employee_id AS employeeId, empBr.club_cd AS clubCode, empBr.branch AS branchCode, empBr.role_id AS roleId, 'N' AS defaultBranch, br.name AS description FROM EmployeeBranch empBr INNER JOIN branch br ON empBr.club_cd = br.club_cd AND empBr.branch = br.branch WHERE empBr.employee_id = ? AND empBr.branch = ? 
09:40:10,769 DEBUG getEmployeeBranch:132 - ==> Parameters: DEMO(String), 001(String)
```

Mapper:

```
public EmployeeBranchBean getEmployeeBranch(
            @Param("employeeId") String employeeId,
            @Param("branchId") String branch);
```

Call:

```
EmployeeBranchBean branchBean = EmployeeHandler.instance().getEmployeeBranch(userName, branch);
```

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand you should use explicit joins regardless of the DBMS. They have been around for close to 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling it. And the mapper, if any.

Comment: Posted the call, mapper and log.

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities:

- The data type of the EmployeeBranch.branch column has changed during your migration from SQL Server to Oracle, e.g. from VARCHAR to INT, and your JDBC driver wants to be weird about coercing the Java String into it
- The data type hasn't changed, but it's always been numeric and your switch from a SQL Server JDBC driver to Oracle's is resulting in the weirdness

If you know or discover that the schema definition hasn't changed, an experiment to try is to (temporarily) use the ${} notation to directly inject the "branch" value. Try it both with and without wrapping quotes, e.g.:

```
AND brn.branch = '${branch}'
```

and

```
AND brn.branch = ${branch}
```

See which, if any, give correct results and whether anything blows up. The results of this experiment could provide some additional clues.

Although I've not worked with Oracle recently, I've occasionally been tripped up by similar weirdness in SQL Server and DB2, in that I'd get weird results or none at all. It's been a while so I can't recall specifics, unfortunately, but when I've tangled with this sort of weirdness it has usually been due to data type confusion.